# Using signed integers in JOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

I have a problem quering in JOOQ. How can I use signed integer type in jooq as it doesn't allow to cast it to `UIntegers`. I got the error in this equal method.

```
public List<Movies> getMovie(int movid) {
    return dsl.select().from(MOVIES).where(MOVIES.MOVIE_ID.equal(movid)).limit(1).fetch().into(Movies.class);
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what's the type for MOVIE_ID ? make sure it's integers.

Comment: yes it is integer type

Comment: integers are already signed in Java

Comment: I suspect you are using [tag:mysql], right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that your `MOVIE_ID` column is of type `INTEGER UNSIGNED` in your MySQL database. This is why jOOQ's code generator generated a `Field<UInteger>` for it. You have three options:

#### 1. Keep using unsigned integers

You'll have to convert your `movid` variable to an `UInteger`:

```
MOVIES.MOVIE_ID.equal(UInteger.valueOf(movid))
```

... or:

```
MOVIES.MOVIE_ID.equal(MOVIES.MOVIE_ID.getDataType().convert(movid))
```

#### 2. Stop using unsigned integers in jOOQ

You can instruct the jOOQ code generator not to generate unsigned integers.

```xml
<!-- Generate jOOU data types for your unsigned data types, which are
     not natively supported in Java.
     Defaults to true -->
<unsignedTypes>false</unsignedTypes>
```

Alternatively, you can also use `<forcedTypes/>` in the code generator configuration to enforce unsigned types for individual columns.

[For details, see the relevant section in the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/)

#### 3. Stop using unsigned integers in the database

Another option is to stop using `UNSIGNED` data types in the database, if you prefer to use signed types, of course.

Comment: I went with your first option. It works fine. Thank you